# regular expression to check particular format

Tags: regex, preg-match

How to create an regular expression which checks the string has numbers ,+ , (,) and spaces

```
if (preg_match('/[0-9]/', $val)){
            echo 'Secure enough';
        }
```

Comment: The string must have all these characters?

Comment: yes the string must be either numbers, * ,(,),-,space

Comment: Please dont change the question all together. If you have another question use ask new question . If you change the question as such the answers that are already written for the question irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the regex

```
/^[-0-9+)( ]+$/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jD1pY2/3)

**Example**

```
preg_match("/^[-0-9+)( ]+$/", "1234");
=> True
preg_match("/^[-0-9+)( ]+$/", "12(34)");
=> True
preg_match("/^[-0-9+)( ]+$/", "+1234");
=> True
preg_match("/^[-0-9+)( ]+$/", "1234 123");
=> True
preg_match("/^[-0-9+)( ]+$/", "1234123");
=> True
preg_match("/^[-0-9+)( ]+$/", "12341adf");
=> False
```

Comment: i want to check "-" also

Comment: @RajaManickam Add `-` to start of character class. Edited in answer. Hope it helps you now